# Can I change global MSMQ settings programmatically?

Tags: c#, powershell, msmq

Specifically I'm wondering if I can change the "Limit message storage to (KB)" global setting using Powershell?  I need to turn off this option.  At the moment we aren't doing a programmatic installation of MSMQ so my other option would be to add this to our installation documentation as part of the setup, but I'd like to know if this option is there first before doing that.

Please note that this is the global setting, not the queue setting.

Answer (score 2):

The solution depends on how MSMQ is installed.

- **AD-integrated MSMQ** - The setting is a property of the computer object in Active Directiry
- **Workgroup mode** - The setting is the MachineQuota registry value.

[How to set up computer quotas and queue quotas in Microsoft Message Queuing](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;899612)

Cheers
John

Comment: Hm, this sort of half answers the question in that Powershell would allow you to change the registry if the computer is in workgroup mode, but if you have an AD integrated machine then is there a way to make the machine quota change programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

If this is the rigth registry value for "Limit message Storage to (KB)" how I believe, you can do something like this in the registry provider of powershell.

```
cd hklm:

New-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSMQ\SimpleClient" -Name "MachineQuota" -Value 2048 -PropertyType "DWord"
```

2048 is the default value for MSMQ machine.

Comment: No, the SimpleClient branch indicates you're looking at the Windows CE registry documentation. You want HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSMQ\Parameters\MachineCache.